# Визуальный конструктор товара для сайта

Tags: javascript, html, конструктор, blender

Как делаются такие штуки для сайта http://www.converse.com/uk/en/dyo/converse-custom-chuck-taylor-all-star-%2770-suede-low-top/156580CSS18B.html ?

Визуальный конструктор товара, изменение параметров товара на лету с подсвечиванием целевых областей. Вращение 3D/2D. С дальнейшим сохранением.

Какие технологии? Какие специалисты под это нужны? Есть ли уже готовые фреймворки/решения? Blend4Web? И немаловажно - где поучиться такому (книги, уроки, видео)?

Comment: это CANVAS, делают обычно люди, хорошо знающие его и javascript, у картинки отрезаются области под покраску.

Comment: JS + фото товара + свайпы - это если прям совсем по-колхозному.
Если чуть более серьезно, то canvas + наложение маски, либо закрашивание областей (см. исходники сайта.)
Возможно (но это не точно), есть библиотеки под это дело.

Comment: blend4web и Verdge3d